# How to insert blank bytes, while recording audio using JAVA Sound API?

Tags: java, audio-recording, javasound

I am writing a software in Java, to record small presentations on your PC.

The software has three components as of now :

1. a Webcam Recorder      -> uses openCV
2. a Microphone Recorder  -> uses JAVA Sound API
3. and a PPT displayer    -> uses Apache POI API

I am planning to add writing pad component later .

Approach is to record visual and audio components separately and finally merge the video and audio files using ffmpeg system call.

In the GUI, I have given a button to mute the microphone while recording but video is still getting recorded (may be to avoid some noise while recording).
In the code implementation however, when the audio input is paused I am planning to add byte value 0 in the audio stream, byte array, so as to make sure both audio and video length are same before merging.

Is this approach good ?

If yes, how to know how many bytes to insert in the byte array so as to make it of same length as of video.

If no, please suggest some solution approaches for this problem.

Comment: Not sure how good this approach is. But how many bytes you have to insert depends on your sampling rate and how many bytes per sample you are using. Both numbers are in your `AudioFormat` object.

Comment: I am using the typical constructor for Human voice recording (taken from Java SOund Demo package - Oracle website) which is 44100 - sample rate, sample size in bits - 16, channels - 2, frame size - 4, frame rate - 44100 and bigEndian - false

Comment: I am planning to append bytes for every 1/4th of a second until MUTE button is pressed again. Using Thread.wait() in a loop. So once I know the actual size of bytes from these values , I will just add them in the end of the AudioBuffer array get the Job done !!

Comment: 2 channels * 16bit * 44100samples/s = 176,400 bytes/s

Comment: Thanks !! that helped . Regrading approach : OpenCV allows at max only 30 frames per second, do you have any idea on how to synchronize these two ??

Comment: Well, if one has 30fps and the other 44.1kHz you should be able to do the math to align them. Issues arise, if the two streams run apart for whatever reason. So you might have to resync every couple of secs or so, I guess.